# Why are many drugs in the hydrochloride form?

Tags: organic-chemistry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are solid phase organics often conjugated to HCl?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2627/why-are-solid-phase-organics-often-conjugated-to-hcl)

I'm wondering why a lot of drugs are in this hydrochloride form.

E.g.,

- Cetirizine hydrochloride
- Methylphenidate hydrochloride
- Tramadol hydrochloride

I'm really curious to know why this form is so common for the presentation of a drug.